# java.io.IOException: [DeploymentService:290066]Error occurred while downloading files from Administration Server for deployment request

Tags: java, jenkins, deployment, ear, weblogic12c

I am getting the below error while deploying the ear in the weblogic server through jenkins. Ear deployment is getting stuck showing "deploy Running".

```
java.io.IOException: [DeploymentService:290066]Error occurred while downloading files from Administration Server for deployment request "1,458,644,837,675". Underlying error is: "null"
        at weblogic.deploy.service.datatransferhandlers.HttpDataTransferHandler.getDataAsStream(HttpDataTransferHandler.java:86)
        at weblogic.deploy.service.datatransferhandlers.DataHandlerManager$RemoteDataTransferHandler.getDataAsStream(DataHandlerManager.java:153)
        at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.datamanagement.AppDataUpdate.doDownload(AppDataUpdate.java:39)
        at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.datamanagement.DataUpdate.download(DataUpdate.java:56)
        at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.datamanagement.Data.prepareDataUpdate(Data.java:97)
        at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.BasicDeployment.prepareDataUpdate(BasicDeployment.java:694)
        at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.AbstractOperation.prepareDataUpdate(AbstractOperation.java:913)
        at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.AbstractOperation.stageFilesFromAdminServer(AbstractOperation.java:276)
        at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.createOperations(DeploymentManager.java:1409)
        at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.handleUpdateDeploymentContext(DeploymentManager.java:162)
        at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentServiceDispatcher.updateDeploymentContext(DeploymentServiceDispatcher.java:155)
        at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.doUpdateDeploymentContextCallback(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:147)
        at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.updateDeploymentContext(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:28)
        at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.statemachines.targetserver.ReceivedPrepare.callDeploymentReceivers(ReceivedPrepare.java:203)
        at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.statemachines.targetserver.ReceivedPrepare.handlePrepare(ReceivedPrepare.java:112)
        at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.statemachines.targetserver.ReceivedPrepare.receivedPrepare(ReceivedPrepare.java:52)
        at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.TargetRequestImpl.run(TargetRequestImpl.java:211)
        at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.transport.CommonMessageReceiver$1.run(CommonMessageReceiver.java:457)
        at weblogic.work.SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl$WorkAdapterImpl.run(SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.java:545)
        at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:256)
        at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:221)
```

Answer (score 0):

We had almost the same error and after a brief investigation found out our newly created server doesn't have every auth it needed. I know it's a bit old thread but it might help to somebody.

Answer (score 0):

check the permission inside tmp folder of admin and managed server where code is deployed. ownership should be with the same id with which code is getting deployed.